# I have categories and product table. i want to show the categories which has at least 1 product in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have categories and product table. i want to show the categories which has at least 1 product

Comment: Category::query()
  ->withCount('products')
  ->having('products_count', '>', 0)
  ->get();

Make sure that you had relation in your category model

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make one to many relationship it`s described there: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

And then you can call and check if it has products

Answer (score 0):

Use [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

```php
$categories = Category::has('products')->get();
```

This will return all categories that have at least one product.